# How to prevent lxml removing doctype

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, lxml

Bit of context first. I'd like to have a custom html class where i can beautify the html amongst other things (not exposed in the below code).

I do like lxml library and if I knew how to beautify the html with properly with custom indentation i wouldn't even consider using beautifulsoup, unfortunately I don't so I've come up with this little piece of slow & obfuscated code:

```
import lxml.html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def write_new_line(line, current_indent, indent):
    new_line = ""
    spaces_to_add = (current_indent * indent) - current_indent
    if spaces_to_add > 0:
        for i in range(spaces_to_add):
            new_line += " "
    new_line += str(line) + "\n"
    return new_line


def prettify_html(content, indent=4):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
    pretty_soup = str()
    previous_indent = 0
    for line in soup.prettify().split("\n"):
        current_indent = str(line).find("<")
        if current_indent == -1 or current_indent > previous_indent + 2:
            current_indent = previous_indent + 1
        previous_indent = current_indent
        pretty_soup += write_new_line(line, current_indent, indent)
    return pretty_soup.strip()


class Html:
    def __init__(self, string_or_html):
        if isinstance(string_or_html, str):
            self.html = lxml.html.fromstring(string_or_html)
        else:
            self.html = string_or_html

    def __str__(self):
        return prettify_html(lxml.html.tostring(self.html).decode("utf-8"), indent=4)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import textwrap

    html = textwrap.dedent(
        """
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
            <head>
            </head>
            <body>
            </body>
        </html>
    """
    ).strip()

    print("broken_code".center(80, "-"))
    print(Html(html))

    print("good_code".center(80, "-"))
    print(prettify_html(html))
```

As you can see below, the current class will lead to spit out broken code very easily:

```
----------------------------------broken_code-----------------------------------
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
-----------------------------------good_code------------------------------------
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

You could argue that's not broken code but in my experience not having the original doctype may give problems rendering html very easily.

So the question would be either:

a) How can i beautify my html without losing original information and allowing custom indentation with lxml

or

b) How can i prevent lxml from removing original information so the beautification will be made consistently by BeautifulSoup?

Comment: If you finally need to call `BeautifulSoup`, why you need to use them separately? Why not directly use `soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "lxml")`?

Comment: That's really interesting, didn't even know that was possible. As i mentioned in the question reason why using lxml is because I'd like to use it to achieve other tasks so getting rid of the beautifulsoup dependency while still being able to beautify html (with proper indentation) is the main goal here... I'll be reading about that to see what exactly does although from the name it seems BS will use lxml somehow as a backend parser

Answer (score 1):

Although I don't fully get your point, here is an implementation you may want:

```
class Html:
    def __init__(self, string_or_html):
        if isinstance(string_or_html, str):
            self.html = lxml.html.fromstring(string_or_html)
        else:
            self.html = string_or_html

    def __str__(self):
        doctype = self.html.getroottree().docinfo.doctype
        return lxml.html.tostring(self.html, pretty_print=True, encoding="unicode", doctype=doctype)
```

Comment: This is really interesting, I'll be testing it later but from the name it seems like it'll keep the original html content? That's awesome... would you know how to beautify the string without using BeautifulSoup? Anyway, as i said, I'll test it out later... in the meantime, +1 (assuming it'll keep original doctype)